# SQL query for statistic info

Tags: sql, oracle

So let's assume I have two tables, `cars` and `engines`. Every car has an `id` column and `sold_date` column which points to a date when the car was sold. Every engine has `car_id` and `type` columns, where the first one is a foreign key to the `cars` table and the second is an engine's type name, which can be anything from V1 to V999.

So what I want to get is a list of dates from let's say August 1st to August 3rd with every type of engine and a number of sold cars like this:

```
sold_date   engine_type      number_of_sold_cards

08.01.2015  V8              6
08.01.2015  V6              8
08.01.2015  V4              9

08.02.2015  V8              15
08.02.2015  V6              0
08.02.2015  V4              5

08.03.2015  V8              4
08.03.2015  V6              6
08.03.2015  V4              0
```

The example assumes that for these 3 days were sold only cars with engines' types of V8, V6 and V4. What it means is that if there had been sold 5 types of engines for the period (V8, V6, V4, V2, V0) instead, I'd need 5 rows for every date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition outer join to the rescue!

```
with       cars as (select 1 id, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') sold_date from dual union all
                    select 2 id, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') sold_date from dual union all
                    select 3 id, to_date('02/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') sold_date from dual union all
                    select 4 id, to_date('03/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') sold_date from dual union all
                    select 5 id, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') sold_date from dual union all
                    select 6 id, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') sold_date from dual union all
                    select 7 id, to_date('03/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') sold_date from dual union all
                    select 8 id, to_date('03/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') sold_date from dual union all
                    select 9 id, to_date('02/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') sold_date from dual union all
                    select 10 id, to_date('02/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') sold_date from dual union all
                    select 11 id, to_date('02/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') sold_date from dual union all
                    select 12 id, to_date('04/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') sold_date from dual union all
                    select 13 id, to_date('04/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') sold_date from dual union all
                    select 14 id, to_date('04/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') sold_date from dual union all
                    select 14 id, to_date('04/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') sold_date from dual),
        engines as (select 1 car_id, 'V8' engine_type from dual union all
                    select 2 car_id, 'V8' engine_type from dual union all
                    select 3 car_id, 'V8' engine_type from dual union all
                    select 4 car_id, 'V8' engine_type from dual union all
                    select 5 car_id, 'V4' engine_type from dual union all
                    select 6 car_id, 'V4' engine_type from dual union all
                    select 7 car_id, 'V4' engine_type from dual union all
                    select 8 car_id, 'V4' engine_type from dual union all
                    select 9 car_id, 'V6' engine_type from dual union all
                    select 10 car_id, 'V6' engine_type from dual union all
                    select 11 car_id, 'V6' engine_type from dual union all
                    select 12 car_id, 'V6' engine_type from dual union all
                    select 13 car_id, 'V2' engine_type from dual union all
                    select 14 car_id, 'V2' engine_type from dual union all
                    select 15 car_id, 'V0' engine_type from dual),
   engine_types as (select distinct engine_type from engines),
            res as (select c.id car_id,
                           e.engine_type,
                           c.sold_date
                    from   engines e
                           inner join cars c on (e.car_id = c.id)),
      final_res as (select et.engine_type,
                           res.sold_date
                    from   engine_types et
                           left outer join res on (et.engine_type = res.engine_type)),
           dates as (select to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') - 1 + level dt -- paramaterise the start date
                     from   dual
                     connect by level <= to_date('03/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') - to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + 1 -- paramaterise the start and end dates
                    )
select dts.dt,
       fr.engine_type,
       count(fr.sold_date) cnt
from   dates dts
       left outer join final_res fr partition by (fr.engine_type) on (dts.dt = fr.sold_date)
group by dts.dt,
         fr.engine_type
order by dts.dt,
         fr.engine_type;

DT         ENGINE_TYPE        CNT
---------- ----------- ----------
01/08/2015 V0                   0
01/08/2015 V2                   0
01/08/2015 V4                   2
01/08/2015 V6                   0
01/08/2015 V8                   2
02/08/2015 V0                   0
02/08/2015 V2                   0
02/08/2015 V4                   0
02/08/2015 V6                   3
02/08/2015 V8                   1
03/08/2015 V0                   0
03/08/2015 V2                   0
03/08/2015 V4                   2
03/08/2015 V6                   0
03/08/2015 V8                   1
```

The first and second subqueries ("cars" and "engines") are just mimicking your tables; you would not need to include them in your query.

The "engine_types" subquery is just getting the distinct list of engine_types used in the engines table. If you have some other table that lists the available engine_types, then use that instead.

The "dates" subquery is just generating a list of dates between a given date range - in an ideal world, the start and end dates would be parameterised (assuming this is being run in PL/SQL or some such).

The "res" subquery does the join on the cars and engines table, to get the type of engine sold on each date.

The "final_res" subquery outer joins the res and engine_types subqueries, so that every engine type is listed, along with the sold_date, if it was sold.

Once you have that, then it's easy to do a partition outer join on the final_res subquery to the dates subquery.

Comment: I am sorry I didnt have time to properly check the answer, I will try out your answer tomorrow and accept it if it'll work out since the previous one didn't

Comment: No worries; I hope it does work for your scenario *{:-)

Comment: I've tried it just on the paper and I can't understand how you retrieve those values with 0 in `CNT` column ... If I get it right, rows in `final_res` will have either a date value in its second column or `null`, since it's left join, so those columns with nulls won't get joined in the last query since you join them on their date column, which can be null and we'd get only the rows where`CNT` > 0 ? The last query result that you show is exactly what I want, but I cant get how you get values with zeros in `CNT` :(

Comment: I don't have oracle installed on my home machine, so I may have mixed up some logic ...

Comment: [Here is a good post for understanding partitioned outer joins.](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312) Basically, in the final_res subquery, we have the engine_types along with when they were sold. Then, taking each engine_type by itself, we left join it to the list of dates. Now for engine type V2 we don't have any rows matching with 1st-3rd of August, so we end up with 3 rows for V2 with no sold_date present. Same for V0. But for V4/6/8, you will have some sold_dates present, which can then be counted. Takes a while to get your head around; easier if you can play with the query

Comment: Ps. You could play around with this at sqlfiddle.com, making sure to select the db version as Oracle 11g and building the scheme as empty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join cars and engine tables. Need to count the sold cars and group by sold_date and engine_type:

```
select c.sold_date
      ,e.engine_type
      ,count(*) as number_of_sold_cars 
from cars c
inner join engines e on c.id = e.car_id
where c.sold_date between date '2015-08-01' and date '2015-08-03'
group by c.sold_date,e.engine_type
```

> Update:

With this query you will have all engine types sold in the selected period. You will have 0 for number_of_sold_cars if this engine type is not sold on the particular date:

```
with engine_type as (
select distinct e.engine_type 
from cars c
inner join engines e on c.id = e.car_id
where c.sold_date between date '2015-08-01' and date '2015-08-03'
)
select c.sold_date
      ,t.engine_type
      ,count(*) as number_of_sold_cars 
from cars c
inner join engines e on c.id = e.car_id
left join enginte_type t on t.engine_type = e.engine_type
where c.sold_date between date '2015-08-01' and date '2015-08-03'
group by c.sold_date,t.engine_type
```

Comment: it there weren't sold any cars with V666 engine on the 1st of August but were on the 2nd and 3rd, it won't return a row (08.01.2015--V666--0) for the 1st of August, only the second and the third.

Comment: In the example I can't see type V666? Do you have a table with all the engine types?

Comment: "...engine's type name, which can be anything from V1 to V999", and no I dont but I can get those from `engines` table with `distinct` function, like `select distinct type from engines`

Comment: I think it may work, thank you so much for your time and answer, I know the question was asked poorly and I apologize for that.

Comment: The query loads only rows with `number_of_sold_cards` > 0. So the same thing I mentioned in the first comment still applies :(