# ORACLE SQL - insert date range to existing script

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the following script to get production figures per day. There are some days where there are no production figures so the report does not bring through that date.

```
select distinct 
od.work_center_no, 
case  when od.work_center_no not in ('HPKG','SHRK') then so.revised_qty_due
      when od.work_center_no in ('HPKG','SHRK') then od.allowed_hours
end units_discs, 
case  when od.work_center_no not in ('HPKG','SHRK') then 'units'
      when od.work_center_no in ('HPKG','SHRK') then 'hrs'
end qty_hrs,
trunc(so.revised_due_date), so.plant, so.order_type
from gps_beweg gb, TABLE(leos_flatbom_pkg.GetFlatBOM(gb.part_no)) bom, 
leos_item li, shop_order so, operations_detail od
where gb.cunr = 'W30001'
and bom.av_part_no = li.av_part_no
and li.item_type in ('FP','MD')
and bom.av_part_no = so.part_no
and so.status_code between '2' and '8'
and so.order_no = od.order_no
and od.work_center_no not in ('AVDX','DPRN','FYIE','BVDB','ABDX','BBDS')
and od.work_center_no = 'HPKG'
and so.plant = 'W'
order by trunc(so.revised_due_date)
```

I would like to see these missing dates.
I have the following date range script. I thought that if I ran this script I could join my data by joining the dates.

```
select rownum - 1 + to_date(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') a
  from all_objects
  where rownum < to_date(SYSDATE+90, 'dd/mm/yyyy') -
    to_date(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') + 2
```

But, I don't know how to add the date script to my existing script ... should it be as a sub select (I did try this but I keep getting an error (ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected).

Comment: What is the date? revised_due_date? Don't use subquery, use join

Comment: sysdate is already a date.  Applying the to_date function is redundant.

Comment: It's possible that a partition outer join is what you're after. Perhaps [the answer I gave to an earlier question that was asked today](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31807030/4479309) might be of some use to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get specific number of records use

```
select level from dual
  connect by level < 91
```

use it in join with your select

```
select distinct  od.work_center_no, 
  case
    when od.work_center_no not in ('HPKG','SHRK') then so.revised_qty_due
    when od.work_center_no in ('HPKG','SHRK') then od.allowed_hours
  end units_discs, 
  case
    when od.work_center_no not in ('HPKG','SHRK') then 'units'
    when od.work_center_no in ('HPKG','SHRK') then 'hrs'
  end qty_hrs,
  trunc(so.revised_due_date), so.plant, so.order_type
from gps_beweg gb,
     TABLE(leos_flatbom_pkg.GetFlatBOM(gb.part_no)) bom, 
     leos_item li,
     shop_order so,
     operations_detail od,
     (select trunc(sysdate) + level - 1 a_date from dual
        connect by level <= 90) dates
where trunc(so.revised_due_date(+)) = dates.a_date
  and nvl(gb.cunr,'W30001') = 'W30001'
  and bom.av_part_no = li.av_part_no(+)
  and nvl(li.item_type,'FP') in ('FP','MD')
  and bom.av_part_no(+) = so.part_no
  and nvl(so.status_code,'2') between '2' and '8'
  and so.order_no = od.order_no(+)
  and nvl(od.work_center_no not,'AVDX') in ('AVDX','DPRN','FYIE','BVDB','ABDX','BBDS')
  and nvl(od.work_center_no,'HPKG') = 'HPKG'
  and nvl(so.plant,'W') = 'W'
order by dates.a_date
```

outer joins and nvls are neccessary to select dates without data.